# Intercept rendered HTML

Tags: java, playframework, wkhtmltopdf, playframework-1.x

I am writing a web-application using `Play 1.2.3`. One of the feature is to export a rendered `HTML` page as `PDF`. I already have the `HTML` template rendered dynamically based on the parameters sent by the server.
I am planning to use [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf)  to convert the rendered HTML to PDF. Is there a way in which I can intercept the final `HTML` (processed by the framework by replacing all template tags) for this purpose..? Or is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is already a module for that : http://www.playframework.org/modules/pdf

If you want to do it yourself you can watch in the Controller class how a template is loaded and replace some part to get the rendered template as a string

```
protected static String renderTemplate(String templateName, Map<String,Object> args) {
    try {
        Template template = TemplateLoader.load(template(templateName));
        // Get the template into a String
        return template.render(args);
    } catch (TemplateNotFoundException ex) {
        if (ex.isSourceAvailable()) {
            throw ex;
        }
        StackTraceElement element = PlayException.getInterestingStrackTraceElement(ex);
        if (element != null) {
            throw new TemplateNotFoundException(templateName, Play.classes.getApplicationClass(element.getClassName()), element.getLineNumber());
        } else {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Seb I tried Play's PDF module and it was able to generate a PDF out of the HTML template. However, my HTML has both horizontal and vertical scrolling due to large amount of data. The generated PDF handles vertical scrolling, but not horizontal scrolling. For example, in the HTML table some of the columns on the right (beyond the visible page) is chopped off. Is this a known bug?

Comment: With pdf rendering you have to deal with page width and set your table dimensions accordingly. I never faced the problem of horizontal scrolling so I don't know if this is managed by the pdf modules. You may have a look at yahpconverter site (there is not a lot of doc) for this

Comment: I may have phrased my problem poorly in the previous comment. For example, if I make some dynamic changes to the rendered HTML via Javascript in pageload, they won't be available to the PDF module. Right?